Google Sheets - How to get different results for different dividing conditions?
I am trying to find a way for google sheets to change the result of a division equation based on two different conditions. If it is dividing a 0 by a 0, I want it to be blank (so I use IFERROR and then leave it blank, that part is working).
Where I am struggling is when I want a 0 to show as the result IF it is dividing a number greater than 0 by 0.
Example: I am tracking qts of oil used per flight hour, and I have a column for each. If a plane flew for 10 hours and used 0 qts of oil, I want the result cell to show 0. If there is no data, the plane flew for 0 hours and used 0 qts, I want it to keep showing a blank cell.
TIA!
Tried to play around with the IFERROR and IF functions, but I am not good enough with sheets yet to figure it out.

Do you mean =10/0 would be 0?


If you have the column where the Flight_Hours and Quarts_Oil are present you can play around with that
the conditions you need (if I understood your problem properly):

Quarts_Oil = 0 and Flight_Hours = 0: The answer will be blank cell
Quarts_Oil > 0 and Flight_Hours = 0: The answer will be 0
Quarts_Oil = 0 and Flight_Hours < 0: The answer will be 0
Quarts_Oil > 0 and Flight_Hours > 0: The answer will be Quarts_Oil/Flight_Hours

The formula:
=IF(Quarts_Oil=0, IF(Flight_Hours=0,"",0), IFERROR(Quarts_Oil/Flight_Hours, 0))

change Quarts_Oil and Flight_Hours according to your columns

I agree that is what the OP says that he wants. But it makes absolutely no engineering sense to hide oil loss when not flying like that. It is a serious problem if an aircraft engine is losing oil when it is sat unused on the tarmac! Perhaps the OP would be kind enough to tell us which airline he works for so that I can avoid flying with them! BTW your case 3 violates causality (negative flying hours really?). #2 should be a serious fault - immediate inspection required and #3 is a violation of the laws of physics.

Thank you for the answer!! Also @MartinBrown ... it is not for an airline, nor is this supposed to be a super in depth sheet tracking oil loss. I am just needing this so that my graphs can show blanks for when we didn't own the aircraft thus it wasn't flying or using our oil, instead of being down at 0 (since we didn't own it yet!). But I also wanted it to reflect when oil wasn't added while we did own it.

let cell B1 =  qts of oil; cell B2 = plane flew time.
let cell B3 be the result cell.
in the cell B3, put in formula below:
=IF(IFNA(B2,0)=0,"",B1/B2)

you will get the expected result

However this means that the proposed code will hide a static oil leak that loses oil when the plane is on the ground by disguising oil loss when not flying as a false zero. If the plane is losing oil even when it is not flying surely the maintenance team need to know about it. For my money the specification is wrong here and the divide of finite losses by zero should be allowed and flagged up as a massive red warning!
